# If $A$ is open and $A\subset B$, is $B$ open?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Is it true that, if $A \subset B$ and $A$ is open, then $B$ is open?

Comment: Why should it ...

Comment: $(0,1) \subset [0,1]$.

Comment: Not even remotely.

Answer (score 13):

No. For instance, $\emptyset$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. In $\mathbb R$, $B=[0,1]$ is closed and $A=]1/4,3/4[$ is open and $A\subset B$ but $B$ is not open.

Comment: It is a counter-example

Comment: closed $\neq$ not open

Comment: Better now. But, ... what @ThePortakal said

Comment: @ThePortakal It is true, for example the empty set is closed and open. But it my case it is not open in $\mathbb R$

Comment: The point is that $B$ is not open. The statement that $B$ is closed is true, but it's not relevant, because being closed has no relationship to being non-open.

Comment: Just say "$B = [0,1]$ is not open".  Then it would be a counter example.  Saying "$B = [0,1]$ is closed" is ... irrelevant.  You might as well say, "$B = [0,1]$ contains the reciprical of the square root of 2 and $A = (1/4,3/4)$ is open and $A \subset B$ but $B$ is not open."

Answer (score 2):

It's not true. Here is a counter-example: in $\mathbb{R}$, take $A = ]3,4[$ and $B = [1,5]$. Then $A$ is open, and $A \subset B$, but $B$ is not open.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it.

If this were true then if there exists *any* open set $A$ say $(5,5.00000000001)$ then any set containing $A$, say $[5,5.00000000001]$ or $(3,8]$ or $[-527, 60000005670009]$ would have to also be open.

But why should they?  Why should a teeny-weeny sliver of a section of set $B$ force something to be true about the huge honking entirety of the set?

Worst yet $\emptyset$ is open.  And $\emptyset \subset X$ for all sets so *all* sets would be open.

Think about it.

So, no, this is absolutely not even remotely true.